# Getting Parser Error: inconsistent cell count within the table - while running tests in Parallel - Selenium Cucumber Maven framework with Junit

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit, parallel-testing

I have configured Selenium-cucumber maven framework with Junit. After adding the cucumber-jvm-parallel plugin & maven-surefire plugin , commented the statements inside @CucumberOptions which we have written inside TestRunnerTest.java file .After configuring like this, run through CLI . Then my test script fails. But Runners are created automatically for the feature file.

POM file is shown below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>selcuc</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoEurasia</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CucumberParallel</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <version.cucumber>3.0.2</version.cucumber>
<timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
 <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <!-- <dependency>
       <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency> -->

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
<version>1.0.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.12.2</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>          
            </configuration>
          </plugin> 

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
<executions>
     <execution>
         <id>acceptance-test</id>
         <phase>integration-test</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>test</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
             <forkCount>2</forkCount>
             <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
             <includes>
             <include>**/*IT.class</include>
             </includes>
         </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>


<plugin>
<groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generateRunners</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <glue>stepDefinition</glue>
            <outputDirectory>target/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
            <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/</featuresDirectory>
            <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
            <format>html</format>
            <strict>true</strict>
            <monochrome>true</monochrome>
            <tags>"~@ignore"</tags>
            <filterFeaturesByTags>true</filterFeaturesByTags>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

TestRunnerTest.java is shown below :

```
package testRunner;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
//  features = "src/test/resources/1login.feature"
//          ,  tags= {"@Login or @quickSearch"}
//          , glue= {"stepDefinition"}
//  , plugin = { "com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"}, 
            monochrome = true

public class TestRunnerTest {
    public static WebDriver driver;
public static String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(new Date());
public static String browserName;
    private static TestRunnerTest sharedInstance = new TestRunnerTest();

 private TestRunnerTest() { }

 public static TestRunnerTest getInstance() {
        return sharedInstance;
    }

 @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {   
     browserName = System.getProperty("browserName");
            if(browserName==null)
            {
                browserName= "firefox";
            }

        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) 
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\ChromeDriverNew\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
        } 
        else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) 
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\geckoNew\\geckodriver.exe");
             driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } 

        else {
            System.out.println("Error Message----> "
                    + "browser name not mentioned properly");
            System.exit(0);
        }      
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
          // driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   

    }
@AfterClass
    public static void after() {


     Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
              public void run()
              {         
                try {
                     Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));
                    Files.move(Paths.get("target/cucumber-reports"), Paths.get("target/cucumber-reports_ "+ 
                LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("L-d-YYYY h-m-s")) + "_" + browserName), 
                            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
              }


            });

    if(driver!=null) 
    driver.quit();
 }
}
```

Run this in CLI mvn test.
Then getting the below error:

```
@ DemoEurasia ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.901 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-27T15:11:17+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:2
 .1.0:generateRunners (generateRunners) on project DemoEurasia: Execution generat
eRunners of goal com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel- 
 plugin:2.1.0:generateR
 unners failed: Parser errors:
[ERROR] (17:3): inconsistent cell count within the table
```

I don't know where I am wrong. It would be a great help if you guys helped me. Could you please help me guys. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be due to the data you're supplying in your feature files - are you using the same amount of columns for each row?

Answer (score 9):

That happens because some of all the features of the Scenario Outline the Examples table is not complete

for example

```
Examples:
| user | password | rememberAccount |
| user01 |

absolutely all pipelines ( | ) must be completed:

Examples:
| user | password | rememberAccount |
| user01 | | |
```